# How to update an animation state on the WinForms picture box using sprites

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, sprite

I'm supposed to create a simple game with animations on Windows Forms. I decided to use the picture box as a canvas, and draw the game objects on it. The problem is, I can't figure out how I should update states of the game entities. Google says I need to create a timer and every tick to update the game objects and refresh the picture box. And when the event Paint happens, to render the game objects on the canvas. But for some reason, the time passed from the previous update is always different. And it causes animations rendered wrong.

Take a look at the code and find the following line:

```
var dt = (double)(now - LastUpdate).Milliseconds / 1000;
```

There I'm trying to calculate the time passed from the previous tick. It's supposed to be always the value I set to the timer interval: 10 ms. But in reality I see different values such as 1, 5, 30, 500, 900. Because of it a lot of animation frames are missed.

If I try the next code:

```
var dt = (double)MainTimer.Interval / 1000;
```

Then the hardcoded value will improve the entire picture and the animations will become stable. But this approach doesn't work for me either. Because in this case, the speed of animations depends on the computer performance.

What is a correct way to update the state of animations? I haven't found anything except approaches with timers.

Below the full version of the demo code. I also uploaded the VS project on the [GitHub](https://github.com/sergeypogorelov/winforms-sprite-animation).

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var spriteMapImage = Image.FromFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "sprite-map.png");

        #region "Init SpaceShipSprite"
        SpaceShipSprite = new Sprite(spriteMapImage);
        SpaceShipSprite.PositionOnMap.X = 0;
        SpaceShipSprite.PositionOnMap.Y = 0;
        SpaceShipSprite.Size.Width = 39;
        SpaceShipSprite.Size.Height = 39;
        SpaceShipSprite.Animation.Speed = 16;
        SpaceShipSprite.Animation.FrameOrder = new int[] { 0, 1 };
        #endregion

        #region "Init ExplosionSprite"
        ExplosionSprite = new Sprite(spriteMapImage);
        ExplosionSprite.PositionOnMap.X = 0;
        ExplosionSprite.PositionOnMap.Y = 117;
        ExplosionSprite.Size.Width = 39;
        ExplosionSprite.Size.Height = 39;
        ExplosionSprite.Animation.Speed = 16;
        ExplosionSprite.Animation.FrameOrder = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
        #endregion

        LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    protected DateTime LastUpdate;

    protected Sprite SpaceShipSprite { get; set; }

    protected Sprite ExplosionSprite { get; set; }

    protected void MainPictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black);

        SpaceShipSprite.Render(e.Graphics, new Point(0, 0), SpaceShipSprite.Size);
        ExplosionSprite.Render(e.Graphics, new Point(0, 40), ExplosionSprite.Size);
    }

    protected void MainTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;

        var dt = (double)(now - LastUpdate).Milliseconds / 1000;
        //dt = (double)MainTimer.Interval / 1000;

        SpaceShipSprite.Update(dt);
        ExplosionSprite.Update(dt);

        MainPictureBox.Refresh();
    }

    protected void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainTimer.Start();
    }
}

public class Sprite
{
    public Size Size;

    public Point PositionOnMap;

    public Image MapImage { get; private set; }

    public AnimationInfo Animation { get; private set; }

    public Sprite(Image spriteMapImage)
    {
        if (spriteMapImage == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        MapImage = spriteMapImage;
        Animation = new AnimationInfo();
    }

    public void Update(double dt)
    {
        Animation.Update(dt);
    }

    public void Render(Graphics context, Point position, Size size)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        var x = PositionOnMap.X;
        var y = PositionOnMap.Y;

        x += Animation.CurrentFrame * Size.Width;

        var distRect = new Rectangle(position, size);
        var srcRect = new Rectangle(x, y, Size.Width, Size.Height);

        context.DrawImage(MapImage, distRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
}

public class AnimationInfo
{
    public int Speed { get; set; }

    public int[] FrameOrder { get; set; }

    public int CurrentFrame
    {
        get
        {
            if (FrameOrder != null && FrameOrder.Length > 0)
            {
                var index = (int)Math.Floor(_countOfFramesPassed) % FrameOrder.Length;
                return FrameOrder[index];
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void Update(double dt)
    {
        _countOfFramesPassed += Speed * dt;
    }

    private double _countOfFramesPassed;
}
```

Comment: Why divide by 1000? And if you need to divide why not by 1000d ??

Comment: 1000d is really better) thank you for that) but it doesn't solve my issue(

Comment: But why divide ms by 1000 in the 1st place???? µs? really?? Timer, btw has a resolution of being no faster than 20-30ms at best.

Comment: I divide by 1000 because the method awaits the value in seconds, not in milliseconds.

20-30 ms at best? It means the timer approach doesn't work for me... I need FPS 30 as minimum.

Comment: Do you know another approach except the usage of timers?

Comment: No, they are the way to go in winforms. But, as I said Timer will not be better than 15-25 ms resolution! So setting it to 10ms will not result in 10ms intervals really!! So calculating the actual time to find the right positions is a good idea. Of course the time will greatly depend on the load your code creates..